# How to sync data between Azure Mobile Services (ZUMO) and SQLlite on Hybrid mobile apps?

Tags: breeze, synchronization, azure-mobile-services, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a hybrid mobile app and part of the requirement is to allow app to store data offline in SQLLite and sync it later with SQL Azure thru SQL Moblile services.. for this I hav looked into MS Sync Framework, JayData and now looking at BreezeJs

For MS Sync framework I have realized that there is substaintial amount of work required on changing the schema and its pretty outdated. 
With JayData the problem is that it accepts oData but the standard AMS endpoints are JSON feeds...I someone can help me in a way to get that working that will be great..

Now going thru SO questions I have realized that a good number of people are using breezejs with AMS/ZUMO. I have also checked out the sample http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-zumo
I would like to know if it is possible to download data from AMS store it locally in a SQLLite DB and later sync it back with AMD hosted SQL Azure tables using breezejs.

Appreciate all the help in advance.

PS: I am open to any other better alternate/suggestion.

Keep in mind the scenario is HTML/JS SPA Hybrid mobile app

Answer (score 0):

The short version is yes, this is possible.

The longer answer, unfortunately, is that you will be doing a lot of work yourself in this case.

At this point, I would create an Azure Mobile App (an extension to the Azure App Service Web App) connected to your backend database.  Create a table, then do a post of a JSON object to that table URI (which will be something like http://blah.azurewebsites.net/tables/yourtable).  When you retrieve the same table with a GET http://blah.azurewebsites.net/tables/yourtable you will note that the Azure Mobile Apps (or Service) has added some extra fields - explicitly, they are called __updatedAt, __version and __deleted.   If you request a specific Id, then you can also get an ETag to determine validity.

These fields allow you to do offline sync.  Since you know when you last synced, you can then PATCH each updated record (and POST each new record) - for the PATCH, include the __version of the last time you downloaded - the server will tell you if something else conflicted.  Once you've done that, you can GET all records since the last time you synced (it's a standard oData query) and then update your SQLLite DB.

That's a quick walk through of what needs to be done.  the todo-zumo sample on BreezyJS does not do this logic - if you look at the code, you will note that it just does a simple cache utilizing local storage - hardly good for a more complex model.